# Revolving a function around $y$-axis, finding volume using shell method

Tags: calculus, volume

The region bounded by $y= \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^3+8}}$, the $x$-axis, and the line $x=2$ is revolved about the $y$-axis. Find the volume of the solid generated this way.

[Answer= $\frac{8\pi}{3}(2-\sqrt{2})$]

Answer (score 1):

For the rotation around $y$ axis the formula is
$$V=2\pi \int _{a}^{b}xf(x)\,dx$$
In this case we have 
$$ V=2 \pi  \int_0^2 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^3+8}} \, dx=\frac{2\pi}{\color{red}{3}}\int_0^2 \frac{\color{red}{3}x^2}{\sqrt{x^3+8}}\,dx =\frac{2\pi}{3}\left[2 \sqrt{x^3+8}\right]_0^2=\frac{8}{3} \left(2-\sqrt{2}\right) \pi$$
I have multiplied and divided by $\color{red}{3}$ in order to have $3x^2dx$ so the integral becomes
$$\int \frac{d(x^3)}{\sqrt{x^3+8}}=\int (x^3+8)^{-1/2} \,d(x^3)=\frac{1}{1-\frac12}\,(x^3+8)^{1/2}+C=2\sqrt{x^3+8}+C$$
Hope this can be useful